# round to the nearest multiple of 1/16 in C

Tags: c

Please let me know how to round a decimal number like 0.53124 to a nearest multiple of 1/16 which is 0.5. And similarly, when you round 0.46875 we must get 0.5. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
floor(0.53124 * 16 + 0.5) / 16
floor(0.46875 * 16 + 0.5) / 16

floor(x * 16 + 0.5) / 16
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that you can multiply by 16, call `round(double x)` and divide by 16. noob code:

```
double x;
x=x*16;
x=round(x);
x=x/16;
```

and the one line code:

```
double x;
x=round(x*16)/16;
```

Comment: I don't know how to do the round() in C.

Answer (score 1):

C Code:

```
answer = (int) ((x + 1.0/32.0) * 16) / 16.0;
```

Python verification:

```
>>> int(((.53124 + 1.0/32) * 16)) / 16.0
0.5
>>> int(((.46875 + 1.0/32) * 16)) / 16.0
0.5
>>>
```